# Why Does the Fisher Scoring Algorithm "Work"?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, variance, maximum-likelihood

I was reading the following link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_algorithm) on the "**Fisher Scoring Algorithm**". As I understand, the Fisher Scoring Algorithm is similar to the Newton-Raphson Algorithm, but is used more to optimize Likelihood Functions of Statistical and Probabilistic Models.

Here is my understanding of this algorithm:

- Suppose we have observations: $$y_1, y_2, \dots$$
- And suppose these observations have a probability distribution function: $$f(y;\theta)$$
- If we consider the "Score Function" as the first derivative of the log-likelihood function, we can take the First Order Taylor Expansion of the Score Function and write it as follows: $$V(\theta) \approx V(\theta_0) - J(\theta_0)(\theta - \theta_0)$$
- Note that J(thetha) is the negative Hessian of the log-likelihood function : $$J(\theta_0) \approx -\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\triangledown_{\theta}^2 \log \left(f(y_i, \theta)\right)\right)$$
- We can then write the **Fisher Scoring Algorithm** as: $$\theta_{m+1} = \theta_m + J^{-1}(\theta_m)V(\theta_m)$$

In this article, the following two proofs are claimed about the Fisher Scoring Algorithm:

- **Proof 1:** **As the number of iterations (i.e. "m") increases, the estimates from the Fisher Scoring Algorithm converges to the estimates that would have been obtained from Maximum Likelihood Estimation**. As I understand, this is important for the following reason: Suppose you have some complicated Likelihood Function and have difficulty solving the resulting system of equations (e.g. multidimensional, non-linear, etc.) - then, the results of this proof would permit you to indirectly obtain estimates "close" to the estimates that you would have obtained via Maximum Likelihood Estimation (Note: Estimates obtained via MLE are "desirable" as these estimates have useful properties such as Unbiasedness, Consistency, Asymptotic Normality, etc.). In mathematical notation, this proof can be written like this:

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \theta_m = \hat{\theta}_{MLE}$$

- **Proof 2:** To reduce the computational complexity of the Fisher Scoring Algorithm, we often replace J(thetha) with the "Expected Value" of J(thetha) -  we call this I(thetha):

$$\theta_{m+1} = \theta_m + I^{-1}(\theta_m)V(\theta_m)$$

Given this information - **the estimates produced from the Fisher Scoring Algorithm (after many iterations) are expected to have same asymptotic distribution properties as the true estimates under Maximum Likelihood Estimation**. As I understand, this result is important because it allows for statistical inferences made using the results of the Fisher Scoring Algorithm to have similar properties as statistical inferences made using estimates from MLE. In mathematical notation, this proof can be written like this:

$$\sqrt{n}(\theta_{m+1} - \theta_{MLE}) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, I^{-1}(\theta_{MLE}))$$

**My Question: I am trying to understand why the ideas captured within Proof 1 and Proof 2 are true.**

When looking online, I found different references on these topics - but none of these references explicitly explained why these two proofs are true. **Can someone please help me understand why these two proofs are true?**

Thanks!

Comment: my question is asking a different question compared to the alleged duplicate question

Comment: There are lots of ways to ask the same question. The answer to your questions is the same as the answers in the duplicate.